# How is one supposed to stop Chromium processes?

Tags: chromium, process

After I close the Chromium GUI many `chromium-browser` processes continue running indefinitely. It seems like it's running a daemon that keeps processes around so they can be reused.

Checking the manual and help pages for the `chromium-browser` command only lists a small number of 'stable' options, none of which seem to have anything to do with ending child processes.

If I kill them I get a load of notice dialogues in the bottom-right of the screen complaining that various extensions have "crashed".

Is there a proper, less-aggressive way to terminate Chromium processes?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Turns out this is a feature of chromium/chrome where it leaves processes running for extensions. To turn off go to Settings-->Show Advanced Settings-->Background Apps and uncheck the "Continue running background apps when Chromium is closed" option. 
Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/269385/why-does-google-chrome-leave-running-processes-behind-even-after-closing-the-bro

Comment: Thanks! In Chromium 34 it's under "Settings-->Show Advanced Settings-->System". 
It worked for me, but the first time I restarted Chromium it didn't open any of my previous tabs (even though "Continue where you left off" was still on). Further restarts *did* keep my tabs, weird.

Answer (score 2):

You can terminate it from its built in **Task Manager**

right click on tab and choose Task Manager then choose the process you want to kill(in your case you would kill all processes then you can close the browser)

Note that images are taken for chrome not chromium but its the same "nevermind".

[image: Right click on the tab bar and select "Task Manager"]
[image]

Comment: Closing extension processes this way also brings up a pop-up that compains they have "crashed". The process for each pop-up then needs to be ended as well as all the others. This is slower and no more effective than forcibly killing processes from the terminal.

Comment: If you cannot find the task manager menu item, you can access it using 'shift+esc'.